# Is it possible to extend a pojo class in Spring?

Tags: spring, inheritance, javabeans, pojo

I have a pojo which contains a set of private variables and their setters and getters. This pojo is used extensively across my application. Now, I have to support a scenario where there are multiple pojos and each pojo is a superset of the initial pojo I have. Is it possible that I can extend my original pojo so that I need not change my existing business logic.
I am new to spring and I dont know if this is possible.
Pojo B should contain everything in pojo A and few more things. 
Inside the code I will create pojo B objects through pojo A.
Basically, some thing similar to inheritance, but with pojos.

Comment: A POJO is a plain old Java object. How is it related with Spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you would either aggregate or inherit.

Inherit:

```
class A {
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class B extends A {
}
```

Aggregate

```
public interface A {
    public String getName();
}

public class AImpl implements A {
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class BImpl implements A {
    private A wrapped;
    public BImpl(A wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return wrapped.getName();
    }
}
```