# how to write multiples POJO s having same fields in one POJO class

Tags: java, json, spring, web-services

i have 4 POJO clasess having same name,id,location as fields or properties. instead of creating four POJO s with same fields,is it possible to write all the fields in one POJO class?

Ex:test.java

```
private id
private location
private name
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are these the only fields in all four classes? In that case you don't need to create 4 classes but 4 instances of the same class..

Comment: Your question seems a bit light on details. Please flesh it out a bit.

Comment: Why do you need multiple classes with the exact same fields? I am not sure whether you just started learning Java or this is for some specific need. I am going to assume this is for your homework and until you tell what is the need and why you think having multiple classes solve your issue, I am going to have to down-vote this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to extend a pojo class in Spring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390581/is-it-possible-to-extend-a-pojo-class-in-spring)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you can use inheritance. So you can create the superclass that defines the fields in question. Then any class that extends this one automatically inherits these fields. You can then add additional fields to the subclass if needed. This is a very simple example.

```
public class Test{

    private int id;
    private Location location;
    private String name;

    public Test( int id, Location location, String name ){
        this.id = id;
        this.location = location;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then as suggested use inheritance:

```
public class TestA extends Test{

    public TestA( int id, Location location, String name ){
        super( id, location, name );
    } 
}
```